# How do I make onchange event fire before onclick event (Bootstrap 4 Radio Buttons)

Tags: jquery

So, here's my problem - In my progress slider, I have a portion of pages in which I want to collect data on the radio button clicked, and limit the possibilities of the next one, and so on (goes on for four pages), to do that I used the onchange command, got a number from the id of the  checked radio button in the div, then, on the arrow click command, i use the .slice command to get the buttons with values higher than the value I chose before and disable them and their parent with a class. now, when I tried using .click instead of .change, for whatever reason, the click event fires before the value is set, and when the page turns, the .slice command ends up using the old values (0 by default, so the slice commands cuts out every option but the first), basically, it updates the cut value after the page is switched.

I'm using a slider (with pages) I made for the preferences portion of my ASP.NET school website and wanted to make it so when you can click the radio buttons in every page, you move on to the next page, instead and in addition to using the existing arrow buttons, simple enough (I thought) - just make it so when you click the labels, the parents of the radio buttons (That's how they're built in Bootstrap), you trigger the click event of the right arrow, but that leads to the problem I mentioned before. 
I tried a couple of things to combat it - first, I tried putting it so clicking on inputs is disabled on those pages, putting the click event inside the onchange event - which worked, but created a separate problem, the values were being updated, but the active class was for whatever reason, not given to the parent label, which is a huge problem, because you can go back with the arrows and change values, and when you go back to it, you can't see it selected, like you can see with other radio buttons, I also tried to combo this, but nothing I did seemed to work, hell, I even tried giving the active class in the change command, but to no avail, only thing that came close was a bug that I forgot to put a $ in one of the if statements in the arrow click event, fixing the bug or deleting the if statement made the active class not work again in these pages, it was so strange... also I should mention that I also tried putting .click at the end of the change event, using .click on the labels instead of .change and more..

First function is meant to lock pages until the user presses the radio button, second function is the click the radio buttons to move pages,  the third option is supposed to be if you go back in pages and want to press the same answer to get to the next page (because .change won't detect it)

Right now, it only uses the second function to go to another page - double clicking (only on those four pages, works perfectly fine on other pages), and of course, the arrows are still functional.

Help is much, much appreciated

Comment: You can't change the order in which events are fired; you'll need to refactor your code.    For what it's worth, using `radio` buttons to trigger navigation is *far* from ideal from a UX standpoint; it's not clear to me why you're doing that, but switching to more standard links or buttons may make the problem you're having evaporate anyway.

Comment: @DanielBeck so you're saying I should either stop using the radios as navigation and go back to only using the arrows or make the radios buttons instead, got it, thanks for the explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On those type of cases in javascript you must setup a timeout and postpone some ms the processing. Sometimes there are better solutions, but sometimes in JS is the only way.

On your current event code place a setTimeout surrounding your code:

`setTimeout(function() {
   ...your current code...
}, 1);`

And test. Sometimes you must increase the 1ms of delay a bit depending on the event, up to 333ms (more than 333ms are human perceptible).

Also, some commands like navigations are forbidden if triggered on a timeout, but if the timeout is just after the main input event the operation is allowed. Because of this, when used postponed code is not a good idea to increase delay and testing of various browsers and devices is recommended.

Comment: Thank you ever so much, for whatever reason didn't think timeout would work, all I needed was 1ms, cheers